# Searching through a list of child subjects

Tags: java, parent-child, bluej

So my issue is trying to use the getName() and getPhone() methods (in class Contact) in the main method.

I don't know how to use them in this context with all 3 classes.

[Here is what the program is supposed to be doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPTP4.png)

Apologies if this is not too concise, I just started programming recently.

```
public class LookupPhonebook{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phonebook phonebook = new Phonebook("Sam Johnson");
        phonebook.addContact(new Contact("Kelly Wong", "(02) 12345678"));
        phonebook.addContact(new Contact("Richard Jackson", "(02) 87654321"));
        phonebook.show();

        String searchName = Input.askString("Enter a contact name: ");
        phonebook.findContactByName(searchName);
        if (searchName.equals(phonebook.getName())) {
            System.out.println("Phone number is " + phonebook.getPhone());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(searchName + " not found");
        }
    }
}

import java.util.*;
public class Phonebook {
    private String owner;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public Phonebook(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        contacts.add(contact);
    }

    public void show(){
        System.out.println(owner + "'s phonebook");
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            System.out.println(contact);
        }
    }

    public Contact findContactByName(String name) {
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            if (contact.getName().equals(name)) {
                return contact;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return null;    
    }
}

public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String phone;

    public Contact(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + phone;
    }
}
```

This method is the only one used in a class provided to help with the exercise.

```
/**
 * Asks the user the given question, waits for the user to enter a
 * single character at the keyboard, and then returns this character.
 *
 * @param question the question to be printed
 * @return the character that the user entered as an answer to the question
 */
public static char askChar(String question) {
    System.out.print(question + " ");
    return scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the result from `findContactByName` to a local variable following the instruction. The original program just throw away the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Phonebook phonebook = new Phonebook("Sam Johnson");
    phonebook.addContact(new Contact("Kelly Wong", "(02) 12345678"));
    phonebook.addContact(new Contact("Richard Jackson", "(02) 87654321"));
    phonebook.show();

    String searchName = Input.askString("Enter a contact name: ");
    // 2. Search contact and store is local variable
    Contact result = phonebook.findContactByName(searchName);
    // 3. If we found contact
    if (result != null) {
        System.out.println("Phone number is " + result.getPhone());
    } else {
    // 4. No contact is found
        System.out.println(searchName + " not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this it was very helpful.